# Changing the value of a private primitive variable in C++

Tags: c++, class, private-members

```
class A {
    private:
        int numberOfElements;

    public:
        A() : numberOfElements(0) {}
        void add() { numberOfElements++; }
```

The value of numberOfElements remains 0.

```
void PhoneBook::add(std::string name, std::string phoneNumber) {
entries[numberOfElements] = Entry(name, phoneNumber);
numberOfElements++;
}
```

That is the actual code that is supposed to increment the variable in my application. Class A is just a sample of what my original class looks like.

```
std::string PhoneBook::find(std::string name) {
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    if(entries[i].getName().compare(name) == 0) {
        return entries[i].getPhoneNumber();
    }
    return "Name not found";
}
}
```

I printed out the value of i to see what it was and it remains at 0.

```
void PhoneBook::add(std::string name, std::string phoneNumber) {
entries[numberOfElements] = Entry(name, phoneNumber);
numberOfElements++;
}

std::ifstream in;
in.open("phonebook.txt");

while(in >> name && in >> phoneNumber) {
    book.add(name, phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Can you also show us the code that tests your claim, perhaps that's where the error is?

Comment: Didn't happen without an [mcve]

Comment: @nos is my edit what you were asking for ? Those are all the locations in which the variable numberOfElements comes in to play.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm No, there's no code there that calls add() at all. I'm asking for the code that made you claim that your add() function doesn't increment `numberOfElements`. e.g this works fine: https://ideone.com/LHiHVT

Comment: @nos fixed, book is a PhoneBook object

Comment: @nos Ok, so i figured out that the problem is that the variable numberOfElements does get incremented but in the find function itself it remains 0

Comment: Pass those strings by const reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string PhoneBook::find(std::string name) {
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    if(entries[i].getName().compare(name) == 0) {
        return entries[i].getPhoneNumber();
    }
    // end of if, still in the loop
    return "Name not found";
    // we never get past this, so the loop will
    // run no more than a single time
}
}
```

The issue is probably that you're terminating your find function earlier than wanted. Putting the return statement outside of the for loop should fix this:

```
std::string PhoneBook::find(std::string const & name) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        if(entries[i].getName().compare(name) == 0) {
            return entries[i].getPhoneNumber();
        }
    }
    return "Name not found";
}
```

Note that I changed indentation. Having clearly indented code helps to prevent such mistakes. *(I also changed the function to accept a const reference, this removes the need to make a useless copy)*

Comment: I apologize for using SO for such a small mistake. Thank You.

Comment: Happens. Note the thing about the const reference, as suggested in the comments.